# Qlik Sense - Possible to freeze column in Straight table

Tags: qliksense

Chart exploration in Straight table allows users that do not have edit rights to customize the original straight table when they are in analysis mode. These users can add or remove columns as they want, but is it possible to freeze a column?

Answer (score 0):

The chart exploration feature of the Straight Table object allows dashboard users to hide/show and reorder the columns of the table **just for that session**. It does not permanently change the table, it's just a way to see a modified view of the table and still does not allow users to add new columns or change any settings. When users change the table view, it only changes it for them (no other users see that exploration) and the table is reset back to the original state when the user leaves the dashboard.

The only exception to this is when a user or developer creates a bookmark that saves object layouts -- only when that bookmark is used would the chart exploration changes persist for that table. You cannot disable the "save layout" feature of bookmark creation in an app.

If the Chart Exploration feature does not meet the needs of your dashboard, you can simply disable it:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense Straight Table settings for disabling Chart Exploration]

An alternative to using Chart Exploration may be to set up a sort of custom report where the users can choose fields from a filter pane to show in the table. To set that up:

- Add a filter pane to your sheet and add this as your field: `=[$Field]`.
- Disabled Chart Exploration in your Straight Table object.
- For each **dimension** in your table, add this expression to the **Show column if** property: `=Match(GetObjectDimension(0), '$(=GetFieldSelections([$Field], ''','''))')`.

  - Change the index in `GetObjectDimension(0)` to match the index of each dimension in your table.
- If your table includes **measures**, you can define a custom list in a table in your data model and then use that in another filter pane. Then perform the above steps for the measures using `=Match(GetObjectMeasure(0), '$(=GetFieldSelections([MyMeasuresList], ''','''))')`.

[image: Screen recording of using a custom table report in Qlik Sense]